# Куда мне всунуть аргумент self?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Вот ошибка если я НЕ вставляю в скобки аргумент self:

```
File "F:\Programming\Assistant\Yulia_0_1_5.py", line 192, in
button.config(command=lambda: main()) # Вызов кнопкой функции main()
TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Вот ошибка если я ВСТАВЛЯЮ аргумент self в скобки:

```
File "F:\Programming\Assistant\Yulia_0_1_5.py", line 192, in
button.config(command=lambda: main(self)) # Вызов кнопкой функции main()
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Вот место в коде:

```
button.config(command=lambda: main(self)) # Вызов кнопкой функции main(self)
```

Аргумент `self` находится в скобках названия функции, тобишь, выглядит так - `def main(self)`. Этот аргумент нужен для работы базы данных.
Вопрос: куда мне нужно всунуть аргумент `self`? P.S. Что значит `lambda:` я не знаю.

Comment: Если у вас код не в методе какого-то класса, то ниоткуда не возьмете. self сам по себе не имеет отношения к базе данных, это просто ссылка на объект, от которого вызывается метод.

Comment: @insolor, Я просто вырвал код из другого файла потому что разобрался лишь на примитивном уровне по типу "Вот это сюда, вот это здесь, вот это по идее туда".

Comment: @insolor, я сейчас убрал класс от этой базы данных, но я без понятия чем это может помочь. Всё равно выдаёт ту же ошибку:
  File "F:\Programming\Assistant\Yulia_0_1_5.py", line 192, in <lambda>
    button.config(command=lambda: main()) # Вызов кнопкой функции main()
TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Если просто вырвать метод из класса, и использовать как просто функцию, работать скорее всего не будет. "я сейчас убрал класс от этой базы данных, но я без понятия чем это может помочь" - я без понятия зачем вы это сделали.

Answer (score 1):

`main` это функция в каком-то классе, допустим так:

```
class SomeClass:
   def main(self):
      ...
```

Чтоб вызвать метод `main` у этого класса вам нужен объект класса `SomeClass` и, если допустить, что у вас есть на объект ссылка в переменной `some_class_obj`, то вызов будет выглядеть так:

```
button.config(command=lambda: some_class_obj.main())
```

При вызове `some_class_obj.main()` внутри `main` ссылка на `some_class_obj` будет автоматически передана в первом аргументе, т.е. `self`.

Где в вашей ситуации взять объект, зависит от структуры программы.

Comment: В той кнопке вызывается сама функция, тобишь, не что то ИЗ функции, а вся целая функция. Всё равно что в конце взять и прописать main(). Я добавил к функции вот так main(self) потому что я взял код из другого файла и не сильно разобрался в его работе, но понял что в аргументы функции нужно прописать self для работы этого кода. Вот для удобства начало функции. Самое важное.
 def main(self): # Главная функция

    speak("Здравствуй, я голосовой ассистент Юля. Версия 0.1.5.")

    while True: # Главный цикл
        db = DateBase._getDate()
        self.date = DateBase._getDate()

Comment: Код нужно не комментарием писать, а добавлять в нормальном отформатированном виде в вопрос кнопкой "править". Я не понял, что вы хотите сказать комментарием. Особенно вот это `не что то ИЗ функции, а вся целая функция`